# Detect & replace long string with Javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to detect **long visible strings** that are within random HTML elements, E.g. detect strings longer than 100 chars like some URLs. The use case is to avoid these strings from WYSIWYG input as those break the UI.

How can I do it with Javascript or jQuery?

E.g. how can I detect the string longer than 100 chars (the URL, but **without** looking for URLs with regex) in this HTML? Starting at selector `#content`:

Bonus for being able to replace it with a shorter string

```html
<div id="content">
  <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; width:100%; border-collapse:collapse; color:#595959; background-color:#F7F7F7; font-size: 11pt;">
    <tbody style="font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;">
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic
          typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>It has https://www.google.com/search?q=search+term+coronavirus+is+fake&rlz=1C1GCEB_enNL890NL890&ei=RzKIXvv9Oo3XkwXRgIG4CQ&start=50&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwi7veqJm87oAhWN66QKHVFAAJc4KBDw0wN6BAgLED4&biw=1842&bih=1115 survived not only five centuries, but
          also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Not able to get your question here. Find what? replace with what? "_without looking for URLs with regex_" means what?

Comment: Take a look at the URL in the 3rd <tr>. It is a long one. I need to detect any string longer than 100 characters within the HTML.

Comment: You can simply use `document.querySelectorAll('td').forEach(el => console.log(el.textContent.length))` to find that.

Comment: @DanielFerreira What have you tried yourself? Remember StackOverflow is not a coding service.

Comment: @palaѕн that will count all content of the 'td', not individual words. Also I don't know if content will be in a 'td' because I'm validating input from a WYSIWYG editor. I have to start in ` #content `.  
@CarstenLøvboAndersen I've tried and searched for this. It is not an easy one I think.

Comment: For word count, you can use `el.textContent.trim().split(/\s+/).length`

Comment: Can you not use CSS `text-overflow`..?

Comment: @Stuart unfortunately the content is going to be presented in an Outlook Desktop email, which does not support that :-(

Comment: @palaѕн a bit harsh to close a question just because you do not quite understand what OP wants. It was clear to me and I understand why OP had not been able to easily find examples to use since it is not a trivial task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this - note it took me a long time to figure out why the replace did not like the &

I assume the long texts are not found inside HREFs for example. If so, we need more processing

NOTE: There is only one string in your text that is longer than 100 chars so I limited on 80 chars

```js
$(function() {
  const $content = $("#content");
  let html = $content.html()
  $content.text().split(/\s+/gm)
    .filter(str => str.trim().length > 80)
    .forEach(str => {
      str = str.replace(/\&/g, "&amp;")
      html = html.replace(str, `<span class="replace">${str.slice(0,50)+"..."}</span>`);
    })
  $content.html(html);
})
```

```css
.replace {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; width:100%; border-collapse:collapse; color:#595959; background-color:#F7F7F7; font-size: 11pt;">
    <tbody style="font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="1" style="padding:10px">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="1" align="left" valign="top" style="padding:10px">Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61024961/detect-replace-long-string-with-javascript-or-jquery#to make
          a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="1" align="left" valign="top" style="padding:10px">It has https://www.google.com/search?q=search+term+coronavirus+is+fake&rlz=1C1GCEB_enNL890NL890&ei=RzKIXvv9Oo3XkwXRgIG4CQ&start=50&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwi7veqJm87oAhWN66QKHVFAAJc4KBDw0wN6BAgLED4&biw=1842&bih=1115 survived not only five centuries, but
          also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Your assumptions are correct. Much appreciated!